# How do you search for specific text in an entire string of text using RegEx in Notepad++?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to capture specific text in a log file that will only capture text within the first 25 character of a line of text.  This is using the Analyse Plugin in Notepad++.

Example:

```
0.469132 CANFD   1 Rx        122f1                                   1 0 d 32 05 d3 07 ca 00 1f 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In the example above,  I have written the following regex code

RegEx code:

```
(x|rx\s+(...))\s+\d\s+\d\s+(\d|\D)\s+(\d|\D|\d\d|\D\D)\s+.*?(?:(02\s(11|51)\s01))
```

This code will return the line if it sees 11 01 or 51 01 but I don't want to search the entire line I only want to search the next 25 characters after the `\d\s+\d\s+(\d|\D)\s+(\d|\D|\d\d|\D\D)`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Please provide exact requirements, sample input and expected result. A good addition would be some [working demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4r0hai/1).

Comment: Whatever you are trying to match here and should be matched within the first 25 characters, you can put a *negative lookbehind* after to prevent matching if more characters in front: [...`(11|51)(?<!.{26})\s`](https://regex101.com/r/2UwRFu/1)

Comment: Here's a working demo (https://regexr.com/7465b) showing the group 02 11 01 or 02 51 01 being captured in the text.  What I'm looking to do is only capture that group with the first 26 characters after this expression (x|rx\s+(...))\s+\d\s+\d\s+(\d|\D)\s+(\d|\D|\d\d|\D\D)\s

Comment: Your pattern is the same as `\d\s+\d\s+(.)\s+(.)` See https://regex101.com/r/aLO6NY/1 Can you be more specific about after which pattern you want to start the match for 11 01 or 51 01?

Comment: @Thefourthbird \d\s+\d\s+(.)\s+(.) is a much simpler pattern.   Basically, I would want to search for 11 01 and 51 01 right after that pattern.  So it would be \d\s+\d\s+(.)\s+(.) followed by \s+.*?(?:02 (11|51) 01).   This is what I currently have as my search, but I don't want it searching the entire line, I only want it to search the next 26 characters after \d\s+\d\s+(.)\s+(.)

I'm not sure how else to word this.  In my example here (https://regexr.com/7465b) I rewrote the expression using the pattern you mentioned.  This is how I currently have been searching for 11 01 and 51 01.

Comment: @ChrisWenson Like this? `\d\s+\d\s+.\s+.\s+.*?\K02 [15]1 01`  https://regex101.com/r/ojewzR/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird No, that's returning the 51 01, and that exceeds the 26-character limit after the expression \d\s+\d\s+(.)\s+(.).  Again, this is hard to explain over text but for example, in the text here(1 0 f 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 51 01 )  let's say I want to search the first 26 characters after the 64 here for the [1,5]1 01.  How would I write that in the expression?

Comment: @ChrisWenson You can limit the number of characters between substrings matched by setting a range like `a.{0,15}b` which reads "match a followed by b if there are 0 to 15 characters (except line breaks) between them". You could add a question mark to make it lazy, too, for `a.{0,15}?b` which would make the engine look for the shortest match within those 15 possible characters.